# Uniqueness of minimum spanning tree

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

If G has a unique minimum spanning tree, does that mean the edge weights in G are also unique? if yes why and if no why?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I know that if the edge weights in G are unique, then G has a unique minimum spanning tree I'm just curious what we reverse the condition.

Comment: Trees have a unique minimum spanning tree.

Comment: but that did not answer my question :)

Comment: If you think about it a bit more, it does. Or, rather, it contains exactly enough information for you to answer your question.

Comment: ohhhh so it's true if G is a tree then it will have MST and according to the property of MST if its a MST then it must have formed from unique weights, am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is a tree, it has a unique MST whatever its weights are.  The weights could be unique, all the same, anything.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: If $G$ has a unique MST, then are the edge weights necessarily distinct?

The answer is no.  If $G$ is a tree with all edges having the same weight, then $G$ has a unique MST.

More generally, a minimum weight spanning tree must contain every edge that is a bridge (a bridge is an edge whose removal disconnects the graph).  Consider a graph which contains two bridges, both having the same weight, and with the edges in the rest of the graph having distinct weights. Such a graph has a unique MST even though the edge weights are not all distinct because the bridges have the same weight.